# Different Syntax for functions in Scala

Tags: scala

I have the following two methods in Scala:

```
def myFunc: Int => String = { age =>
  "Here " + age
}

def myFunc2 (age: Int) : String = {
  "Here" + age
}
```

Is there any difference in these two methods? (other than the names of course). The syntax looks quite different to me. Is it just a matter of style? Is one prefered over the other?

Comment: You don't have functions here. These are methods. One of them *evaluates to* a function, and you could *convert* these to functions, but the code you've posted only defines methods.

Comment: Ok - good point. I have corrected the terminology. Is there any difference in the two methods though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a difference. The former is a method which takes no arguments and returns a function of type `Function1[Int, String]`. The latter is a method taking a `String` and returning an `Int`.

In Scala, methods with arity-0 can be declared and invoked without parenthesis, so invoking `myFunction(1)` and `myFunction2(1)`  looks the same.

If we'd convert both *methods* to *functions*, you'd see the difference in the fact that the former would take the shape of `Function0[Function1[Int, String]]`, while the latter would be `Function1[Int, String]`:

```
myFunc: Int => String
myFunc2: (age: Int)String

scala> myFunc _
res6: () => Int => String = <function0>

scala> myFunc2 _
res7: Int => String = <function1>
```

Comment: I think you might have the terms "former" and "latter" mixed up.

Comment: @user2357112 Yup, you're right. Fixed that up, thanks!